# View a no show from CollectionView Item

Tags: swift, macos, collectionview

I'm converting an application that has a CollectionView from Objective C to Swift 4.0.  I have much of it converted but I've run into a problem with displaying a subview then selecting a button in the CollectionViewItem class.  I defined my collection view on the main storyboard and created a separate class (CollectionViewItem) and xib for the collection view item (as done in Ray Wenderlich's tut on CollectionView).

[mainstoryboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEwli.png)

[CollectionViewItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMrHp.png)

I then did the same for the subview (ShowSongInfo).

...didn't have enough cred to post the ShowSongInfo view but right not it is simple and has a single label and button (that dismisses the controller).

I binded the info button in the CollectionViewItem View to the CollectionViewItem's class's IBAction:

```
@IBAction func songInfoPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        var name = " "
        if let song = song {
            name = song.fileName
        }
        
        
        let subview = ShowSongInfo(nibName: NSNib.Name(rawValue: "ShowSongInfo"), bundle: nil)
        self.view.addSubview(subview.view)
        
        print(name)
    }
```

In the ShowSongInfo Class, in the ViewDidLoad method I put a print statement to verify the Class was being called:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("SongInfoDidLoad")
        // Do view setup here.
    }
```

Both print statements appear in the log; no errors are recorded but the ShowSongInfo subview never displays.

I'm not sure what I'm attempting is doable.  In the Objective C App I used a sheet to display the songs tag info.  Here I would love the sheet effect or possibly a popover, but right now I'd love for the ShowSongInfo window to simply appear.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Hello El, the main ViewController (ViewController.swift) is set up in a tabbed view with three scenes; "Play" is the initial view.  The second tab is "Playlist" with PlaylistVC.swift  as its ViewController and Extract the third, with  ExtractVC its ViewController.  The CollectionView is setup in the initial view/Scene, Play.

The CollectionViewItem is setup as its own class and its own xib file.  Since it is not part of the main story board it is binded in  the initial ViewController.swift extension NSCollectionViewDataSource.-

```
func collectionView(_ collectionview: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
    let item = collectionViewItem.makeItem(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfacetemIdentifier(rawValue: "CollectionViewItem"), for: indexPath)
    guard let collectionViewItem = item as? CollectionViewItem else {return item}
    let song = directoryDataLoader.songFileForIndexPath(indexPath)
    collectionViewItem.song = song
    return item
}
```

AppDelegate is not currently in use, but I will be using it for integrating menu commands.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is little information as to what class is responsible for what.  What is play scene?  What class holds the collection view?  A view controller?  Looking at the first screenshot, it seems to me that you are creating the application with AppDelegate.  But you don't mention it.

Comment: El, add more comment above.  Thanks for responding

Comment: Remove the segue connection.  Select Scene and set a storyboard ID so that you can access it from ViewController.swift.

Comment: Thanks El, I have never used this so I will do some research and give it a try.

Comment: From what I'm reading Storyboard ref is for pointing to different storyboards or scenes.  There is no segues, When I edit the ShowSongInfo.xib (the CollectionViewItem) there is no Storyboard Reference object in the Object Library.  Not sure how to make the reference between CollectionViewItem and the storyboard.